# What is the Best extension for RSS?

Tags: asp.net, xml, rss, seo, feed

Who does know what is the best file extension for RSS feed on the site (for SEO):

1. (XML) mysite.com/rss.xml
2. (RSS) mysite.com/rss.rss
3. (HTML) mysite.com/rss.html
4. (ASPX, PHP, etc) mysite.com/rss.aspx
5. (with url params) mysite.com/rss.aspx?param1=val1&param2=val2
6. some other

I'm going to use (3) html on my site, is it ok?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file extension shouldn't matter. In theory, the content of URLs is determined solely by the Content-Type HTTP header. In practice, Internet Explorer means that isn't always entirely true.

Personally, I would try to aim for something along the lines of "/feed/ and leave any mention of technology as far out of it as possible.

Failing that, just don't go for something misleading.

So, in reverse order of preference:

An RSS feed isn't an HTML document, so of all those choices, the only one you should actively avoid is *.html*

Using a server side technology in the URLs ties you (to some extent) to that technology. So the next ones to avoid are 4 and 5 since they mention ASP.NET.

That leaves 1 & 2, which are both fine, and the best explicit choices in that list.

As mentioned above, I'd go with 6 and /feed

Answer (score 0):

I always use .XML and have had no problems.